# Creating a Protected Form in Word 2003 with Using Tab Keys to Move from Field to Field

Tags: microsoft-word, automation, microsoft-word-2003

I have created forms with several form fields in which users can enter text, and I would like

1. users to be able to use the tab key to skip from one form field to
   the next without having to use their mouse to click on each field to
   enter content.
2. However, I **also** want the form to be protected so that users can only
   enter content in the fields and not change anything else.
3. And I would like to be able to do this without having to create a macro as I have no idea how to do this.

I may be wrong, but these goals appear to be irreconcilable. I could use the forms toolbar and protect the form for testing purposes, and this allowed me to use the tab keys to navigate from one form field to the next. However, when the form protection from the toolbar is active, it is apparently not possible to activate the form protection via the tools menu that I used to define which fields I would like users to be able to change.

On the other hand, once I protect the form using the protection options from the tools menu, the form is protected and content can be entered in the appropriate fields, but now the tab key does not assist users in navigating from one form field to the next anymore.

Any hints?

Comment: After trying for days, I figured out how it works, of course right after posting my question. Just in case anyone else makes the same somewhat silly mistake I did, I'm now still posting the answer here.

The problem was that with the document protection options that I accessed via the tools menu, I chose to define the form fields as exceptions to a general document protection, not allowing users any changes **except in the form fields**.

Instead of doing this, I should have chosen the option to allow users only to fill out the form.

Comment: please consider moving that comment to an answer and marking it as accepted